# ng-bootstrap toolip unable to add a newline

Tags: css, angular6, ng-bootstrap

Ng-bootstrap when trying to add new line in tool-tip text. Its not displaying new line. 
Tried `<br/>, <p></p>, &#10; , &#13;, ... etc.`
Can anybody please suggest

Please  find below sample code link
[Sample code link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/analaerxrrn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what ever you did is correct, you can use both `&#10; and &#13;` on top of that you need to write one css to it for class `.tooltip-inner` in style.css

```
.tooltip-inner {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

i have tried in you stack blitz example its working for me.

Comment: If I use this property its giving a solid black color around image any idea how to solve this

Comment: can you post any link with image let me check

Comment: I applied pre-wrap in <img> style instead of class. Now that is not creating solid black color envelop. Anyway Thank you :)

Comment: I found it. My mistake I was already having one css class with same name Anyway Thank you